# How create a square at any position of canvas that can be moved at any position on the canvas

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I have created a square at random position in canvas, but I don't know how do I move it to somewhere else in canvas by dragging it to desired position, please suggest some edits or a new method to achieve the proposed task, I am learning while doing so.

P.S. Attached a screenshot of the output window.

[image]

```
import sys
from random import randint
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow,QPushButton,QWidget
from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5.QtCore import QRect,Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter,QBrush, QPen
from PyQt5 import QtCore


class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window,self).__init__()
        title="TeeSquare"
        left=500
        top=200
        width=500
        height=400
        iconName="square.jpg"
        self.setWindowTitle(title)
        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon(iconName))
        self.setGeometry(left, top, width, height)
        self.should_paint_Rect = False
        self.windowcomponents()
        self.initUI()
        self.show()

    def initUI(self):
        if self.should_paint_Rect:
            self.label=QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
            self.label.setText("circle")

    def windowcomponents(self):
        button=QPushButton("Add", self)
        button.setGeometry(QRect(0, 0, 50, 28))
        button.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon("Add.png"))
        button.setToolTip("Create Square")
        button.clicked.connect(self.paintRect)


    def paintEvent(self, event):
        super().paintEvent(event)
        if self.should_paint_Rect:
            painter = QtGui.QPainter(self)
            painter.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)
            painter.setPen(QPen(Qt.black, 5, Qt.SolidLine))
            painter.drawRect(randint(0,500), randint(0,500), 100, 100)
            self.initUI()
            self.label.move(60,100)

    def paintRect(self, painter):
        self.should_paint_Rect = True
        self.update()

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
Rect=Window()
Rect.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1):

The logic of creating a dynamic element is to indicate a set of specific characteristics that by modifying these, the element is modified.

In this case you could use the center of the square, the dimensions of the square, etc. and that data must be implemented through a data structure that can be created from scratch for example by creating a class that has the information of the rectangle, but in Qt it is not necessary to create that element since it already exists and is QRect.

Now that that element has been identified, you can create a QRect whose top-left is random when the button is pressed, and use that QRect to paint it.

For dragging the procedure is:

- Get the mouse click position.
- Verify that the click is inside the rectangle.
- Calculate the position relative to the rectangle.
- When moving the mouse, the position of the rectangle must be updated based on the position of the mouse press.

Considering all of the above, the solution is:

```py
import random
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()

        self.rect = QtCore.QRect()
        self.drag_position = QtCore.QPoint()

        button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Add", self)
        button.clicked.connect(self.on_clicked)

        self.resize(640, 480)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_clicked(self):
        if self.rect.isNull():
            self.rect = QtCore.QRect(
                QtCore.QPoint(*random.sample(range(200), 2)), QtCore.QSize(100, 100)
            )
            self.update()

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        super().paintEvent(event)
        if not self.rect.isNull():
            painter = QtGui.QPainter(self)
            painter.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing)
            painter.setPen(QtGui.QPen(QtCore.Qt.black, 5, QtCore.Qt.SolidLine))
            painter.drawRect(self.rect)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if self.rect.contains(event.pos()):
            self.drag_position = event.pos() - self.rect.topLeft()
        super().mousePressEvent(event)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if not self.drag_position.isNull():
            self.rect.moveTopLeft(event.pos() - self.drag_position)
            self.update()
        super().mouseMoveEvent(event)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        self.drag_position = QtCore.QPoint()
        super().mouseReleaseEvent(event)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Rect = Window()
    Rect.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: How can I extend it for multiple objects?(create multiple squares and move them in canvas)

Comment: @teecup The logic is similar: 1) create several QRect, 2) detect if the mouse click is on a QRect, 3) Move the QRect of (2).

Comment: @teecup 5) I recommend you try something (take the necessary time: maybe one day, 2 days or a week) and only when nothing works for you then post a new question clearly stating what you want to do, describing what you have tried by showing the code that proves it . Considering that I will not answer anything in the comments. SO is not a SW writing service where the OP says: "Give me code." I already pointed out the specific steps so you should at least try something.

Comment: I have tried to create a list of rectangles to store every instance of QRect and append it to end of the list when mouseReleaseEvent is called but it don't seems to work. What should I do atleast please guide me and suggest me the documentation that I need for the purpose. I didn't find proper documentation and source to learn properly so you are right somehow but I am really wishing to learn.

Comment: @teecup What he asks will never be in the docs. Show that you want to learn by writing a new question **by showing what you have tried** (I already pointed out the steps in my first comment).

Comment: @teecup PLEASE read the docs: https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/signals_slots.html#the-pyqtslot-decorator